# MySQL crashes in Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

Today I started my local Docker container and it suddenly crashes. Yesterday, no issues.

I think this is the problem:

> [InnoDB] Assertion failure: dict0dict.cc:3452:for_table || ref_table thread 139947164014336

I've updated my `docker-compose.yml` file to run with the `innodb_force_recovery` value:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  mysql:
    command: --innodb_force_recovery=2
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DOCKER_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

So now I can start my docker container again but I cannot do any actions since it's in recovery mode.

I've read the [mysql innodb recovery page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

My assumption is that I need to login to the mysql database and drop all tables, it's just a development database so that's no problem but like I said I'm unsure how to proceed. Any tips would be welcome.

Comment: "but I'm unsure how to proceed now"  With doing what ?

Comment: Apologies, I can start the container again, but I cannot do any mysql actions since it's in recovery mode. So I need to "fix" the mysql database so I can start it without using the recovery mode.

Comment: Did you check the options mentioned in this (closed) bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98594  as possible cause of this failure ?

Comment: If you don't care about the data you could just wipe the `./mysql-data` dir contents and the DB would start from scratch.

Comment: I have an identical issue. Been working fine for months, this morning started failing on the same error (dict0dict.cc:3452:for_table). What did you do in the end?

Comment: @AliS the only fix I could think of was to drop the database and recreate it again, for me this was no problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the `command: --innodb_force_recovery=2` I could start my MySQL database again. Then I logged in:

```
 - `docker exec -it ti4-automation-mysql-1 bash`
 - `mysql -u root -p ti4-automation`
```

From there I dropped the database :/ I ran prisma migrate again.